# redirect sent packets + modification - Pcap.Net

Tags: c#, packets, pcap.net

Im using Pcap.Net in a C# app.
While browsing a website, i would need to modify all packets except UDP ones to make them go through a proxy.

I explain why, im using a proxy, but its not as fast as direct connection.
So i would like to modify the http tcp packets to be sent via proxy, but keep all UDP ones to direct connection for speed reasons.

So the Question is, how can i modify a packet to be aborted to be sent to direct connection but instead, send it to proxy?

PS : i already know how to sort my packets to filter the ones i need to modify.

PS2 : for better clarity. How can i change `Destination IP`, `Destination Port` and `Request URI` from a packet my computer is gonna send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net) you can't change packets sent. See Question 1 in [Pcap.Net FAQ](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/FAQ)

You can, however, capture them, modify them and send the modified packets.

This wouldn't prevent the original packets from being sent.

See [Interpreting the packets](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Interpreting-the-packets) and [Sending Packets](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Sending-Packets) in the [Pcap.Net User Guide](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/User-Guide) to learn how to capture packets and send new ones.

I hope this helps,

Boaz.

Comment: thats what i though. packet is only READ while sent. so there is no way to prevent it to be sent... only way is to set up a server as a "man in the middle" between router and lan computers. thanks for your answer